# How to monitor communication in a SOA environment with an intermediary?

Tags: web-services, proxy, soa, monitor, rules

I'm looking for a possiblity to monitor all messages in a SOA enviroment with an intermediary, who'll be designed to enforce different rule-sets over the message's structure and sequences (e.g., let's say it'll check and ensure that Service A has to be consumed before B).

Obviously the first idea that came to mind is how WS-Adressing might help here, but I'm not sure if it does, as I don't really see any mechanism there to ensure that a message will get delivered via a given intermediary (as it is in WS-Routing, which is an outdated proprietary protocol by Microsoft).

Or maybe there's even a different approach that the monitor wouldn't be part of the route but would be notified on request/responses, which might it then again make somehow harder to actively enforce rules.

I'm looking forward to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a "[service firewall"](http://www.infoq.com/articles/service-firewall) either by intercepting all the calls in each service as part of your basic servicehost. Alternatively you can use 3rd party solutions and route all your service calls to them (they will do the intercepting and then forward calls to your services).

You can use ESBs to do the routing (and intercepting) or you can use dedicated solutions like IBM's datapower, XML firewall from Layer7 etc.

Answer (score 1):

For all my (technical) services I use messaging and the command processor pattern, which I [describe here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2012/04/25/what-is-messaging.aspx), without actually calling the pattern name though. I send a message and the framework finds to corresponding class that implements the interface that corresponds to my message. I can create multiple classes that can handle my message, or a single class that handles a multitude of messages. In the article these are classes implementing the IHandleMessages interface.

Either way, as long as I can create multiple classes implementing this interface, and they are all called, I can easily add auditing without adding this logic to my business logic or anything. Just add an additional implementation for every single message, or enhance the framework so it also accepts IHandleMessages implementations. That class can than audit every single message and store all of them centrally.

After doing that, you can find out more information about the messages and the flow. For example, if you put into the header information of your WCF/MSMQ message where it came from and perhaps some unique identifier for that single message, you can track the flow over various components.

[NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) also has this functionality for auditing and the team is working on additional tooling for this, called [ServiceInsight](http://particular.net/ServiceInsight).

Hope this helps.